# "wildignore" and "\{n,m}" type patterns

Tags: pattern

The :help entry for "wildignore" directs me to the following list of file patterns under  *autocmd-patterns*:

```
The pattern is interpreted like mostly used in file names:
    *   matches any sequence of characters; Unusual: includes path
        separators
    ?   matches any single character
    \?  matches a '?'
    .   matches a '.'
    ~   matches a '~'
    ,   separates patterns
    \,  matches a ','
    { } like \( \) in a |pattern|
    ,   inside { }: like \| in a |pattern|
    \}  literal }
    \{  literal {
    \\\{n,m\}  like \{n,m} in a |pattern|
    \   special meaning like in a |pattern|
    [ch]    matches 'c' or 'h'
    [^ch]   match any character but 'c' and 'h'
```

I can't seem to be able to get the `\\\{n,m\}` working, however.  When I try, for example, adding

```
set wildignore+=ntuser.dat.log[0-9]\\\{1,\}
```

to my vimrc, I get the error message `E220: Missing }.`  Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Yes, it says the error was detected while processing my vimrc and refers to a lambda function. My vimrc sources error-free if I remove the wildignore setting.  I still get the error with `vim --noplugin`

Comment: If I delete the lambda functions in my vimrc along with `--noplugin`, then I don't get an error at first, but I get the error once I start loading buffers.  In any case, the wildignore setting doesn't seem to have worked after testing with glob().

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. BTW, have you tested it directly/manually (i.e. open vim and enter/run the `set` command)? Always good to verify it that way before trying it in your vimrc, if you haven't already.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I tried entering it directly and it just fills my screen with E220 when I do `:edit ` and try the wildmenu.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @filbranden, I came here upon the recommendation in Vim's README.md

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.

First, `'wildignore'` takes a list of separate patterns, split by comma, so you actually need to escape the comma with a backslash for it to work inside the `\\\{n,m\}` pattern inside `'wildignore'`. So what you actually need as a value is `ntuser.dat.log[0-9]\\\{1\,\}`.

But, second, the `:set` command will use backslash as an escape character, so in order to get one backslash in the actual value of the option, you need to pass it two (the first one to escape the second.) So, in effect, you need to double the backslashes that you pass.

This is the actual command that works:

```
set wildignore+=ntuser.dat.log[0-9]\\\\\\{1\\,\\}
```

Note that if you use `:set wildignore?` to inspect it later on, you'll see the actual value with the correct number of backslashes, three before the `{` and one before the `,` and `}` each.

---

I tested this setup with files named `ntuser.dat.log` followed by numbers (of varying lengths) and non-numbers that would not match the pattern. It seemed to work as expected for me.

If you want to reproduce my testing:

- Create a test directory and `cd` into it:

```
$ mkdir ~/testwildignore
$ cd ~/testwildignore
```

- Create files named after the wildignore pattern to test:

```
$ touch ntuser.dat.log ntuser.dat.log0000000 ntuser.dat.log00000001123 ntuser.dat.log0 ntuser.dat.log00000001122348y3249873297498 ntuser.dat.log99
```

Of these, all are ignored except for two, the one with no numbers and the one with a letter (`y`) among the numbers.

- Create a local test `vimrc` with only two lines:

```
$ cat test_vimrc
set wildmenu
set wildignore+=ntuser.dat.log[0-9]\\\\\\{1\\,\\}
```

- Start Vim with this vimrc:

```
$ vim -N --noplugin -u test_vimrc
```

- Inside Vim, type `:e`, space, then Tab.

The wildmenu you see will only include:

```
ntuser.dat.log  ntuser.dat.log00000001122348y3249873297498  test_vimrc
:e ntuser.dat.log
```

As you can see, all files except the two that don't match the pattern have been filtered out.

Comment: Ugh. Welcome to backslash hell. :P

Comment: With your command it doesn't give me the error anymore, but I still have the files show up in the wildmenu with a vimrc containing only the command along with `set wildmenu`.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to use `let &` with single quotes

Comment: @D.BenKnoble One problem with `let &` is that it makes it hard to emulate the behavior of `set +=`, which will append a new item and properly add commas when needed...

Comment: @user38527 I updated the answer to include the full set of commands I used to test this setup, and it seems to work as expected for me... If it doesn't work for you, can you please update the question with the steps you're using and what you're seeing that's unexpected (or which files are not being ignored that should)?

Comment: @filbranden I tried your test and I still see all the files appear in the wildmenu using the Vim and gVim (for Windows) that I downloaded from vim.org, but not if I use the Vim packaged in Git for Windows.  The test seems to be working for the latter.

Comment: @user38527 Hmmm interesting, I wonder whether Windows behaves differently... Maybe try some variations in the number of backslashes, or perhaps omit the ones before the comma, and see whether that helps? (I don't happen to have a Windows machine handy that I can use for testing that...)